# How to extract SSML parsing code of espeak to implement SSML parsing at SpeechSynthesisUtterance?

Tags: design, javascript, open-source

[eSpeak](https://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/) implements [SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) parsing. [`SpeechSynthesisUtterance`](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes), at least as implemented at *nix, does not parse SSML input at [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=795371) or [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425523) browsers.

How to identify and extract the relevant portions of `eSpeak` for the purpose of including the code at [Web Speech API](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/) implementations at modern browsers to be able to parse SSML input without an extension or third party web service?

---

If there are any issues with the question, do advise how to improve the inquiry instead of casting downvote of question without providing reasons therefore.

Comment: Seems you need an SSML parser in Javascript.  How about this one?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssml

Comment: @RobertHarvey The issue is not how to produce valid SSML, but how to implement parsing of SSML by `SpeechSynthesisUtterance`. We could use [`meSpeak`](http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) `-m` option, though an error occurred when trying and the gist of the inquiry is to get this implemented at browsers source code.

Comment: Seems that most Google Searches for SSML Parser actually turn up SSML generators.  Wonder why that is.

Comment: SSML is just a flavor of XML.  Couldn't you use an ordinary XML parser?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The Web Speech API has simply not been fully implemented at browsers, see https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-voice/2017OctDec/0000.html, https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Dec/0000.html. Instead there are a number of paid web services which implement SSML parsing, i.e.g.; Alexa, Polly, bluemix/Watson, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "ordinary XML parser"? The output is audio.

Comment: So you want something that takes in SSML and outputs audio that runs in the browser.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes. For the Web Speech API to finally be fully implemented as to SSML parsing - without having to use third party web services. Was able to find references to SSML parsing within `eSpeak` package at *nix, and both `eSpeak` and `meSpeak` have been ported to JavaScript using emscipten - though we are trying to get this implemented in browsers according to the specification

Comment: So what you really need is a SSML to JSGF converter that works in Javascript?

Comment: If you are someone who participates in the standards committees or browser implementations, you should disclose that in your question.

Comment: We need to get the Web Speech API implemented according to the published specification https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes - by whatever means available.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What do you mean by "participates"? Asking the authors and publishers of the specification and "OWNERS"  of the source code at browsers to actually implement the specification which they authored?

Comment: Any answer you receive here is going to be different if you are a browser manufacturer as opposed to an application developer.

Comment: At this point we need one or more answers of any kind. That is, _progress_ towards implementation of the published specification. If we can extract the portion of `eSpeak` which implements SSML parsing we can then take ownership of the implementation at open source browsers and finally get the published specification implemented, whether using WASM, emscripten or other means.

Comment: `If we can extract the portion of eSpeak...` -- What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey From perspective here it is repugnant that SSML parsing is available using web services - for a fee - though not by default at open source browsers.

Comment: I get that.  But you've already proposed a solution to your own problem.  Extract the portions you need from eSpeak, assuming its GPL license is palatable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey _"What prevents you from doing that?"_ At this point lack of experience. That is what spawned this and previous questions relevant to the subject matter. If had the experience would simply do the knowledge for self and focus on getting the code incorporated into open source browsers.

Comment: Well, have you looked at the eSpeak code at all yet?

Comment: What do you think about my idea of creating an SSML to JSGF bridge?

Comment: Yes, at `terminal` using `grep` and https://sourceforge.net/p/espeak/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/, though not familiar with C language

Comment: @RobertHarvey _"What do you think about my idea of creating an SSML to JSGF bridge?"_ We could possibly use `eSpeak` and `NativeMessaging`, now.  Ideally, we would want this implemented according the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#utterance-attributes), https://github.com/w3c/speech-api/issues/10. At this point, a proof of concept by any means necessary would be a start.

Comment: Well, C is just another curly brace language, and it's a small one.  If you're a seasoned programmer, you can grok the entire language in a day, and the entire ecosystem in a week.  You asked for guidance about your question scope; if your question is "tell me how to extract the relevant portions of eSpeak," that's a pretty large scope (akin to consulting services); I'm not sure how random strangers on the Internet are going to be able to help you with that, and we're not really set up to do that here.

Comment: What does "grok" mean? Will certainly try, further. Asked here because someone else might have attempted the same general procedure for a different application. Am not asking for someone to do the work, but for a general outline of the procedures required. Do not want to create a workaround which will need to be worked around again to actually get the POC implemented uniformly at open source browsers. But if that is the only route, to mangle until operable, then so be it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok

Comment: The general procedure would be to reverse-engineer the eSpeak application and rewrite it in javascript.  That will require understanding the C language and the methods and algorithms in eSpeak well enough to perform the translation.

Comment: Yes, gather the general principle of the need to reverse-engineer an existing implementation. Not certain how tightly coupled the SSML parsing portion of `eSpeak` is with other portions of the code. What is the significance of the GPL licence?

Comment: It's a copyleft license.  The FSF would say that it preserves the rights of users.  Commercial enterprises would say that it restricts their freedom by requiring them to redistribute the entire source code of the applications in which so-licensed source code is used.    As with many things in computing, the story is a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html

Comment: But since you'll be rewriting eSpeak in a different programming language anyway... :)

Comment: Not following previous comment. Current development of `eSpeak` is apparently ongoing at https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak/, see https://sourceforge.net/p/espeak/discussion/538921/thread/fb5a5de3/#a303. Will look and ask there if they have an existing distinct SSML parsing module which can be ported to the browser implementations. Am not necessarily trying to rewrite `eSpeak` entirely, but rather utilize the existing SSML parsing code that `eSpeak` uses within the boundaries of the Web Speech API specificaion - if that is feasible. If not, then, yes, compose an entirely different implementation

Comment: Sounds like a good plan.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So far have parsed `<prosody>` and `<voice>` elements using JavaScript https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser, encountered a bug at Chromium when trying to create an algorithm to parse `<break>` element https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797624. Browsing the source code further, it appears as though we only need to pass the appropriate options to either `spd-say` (`-x` or `-ssml`) or `espeak` (`-m`) https://askubuntu.com/questions/991314/how-to-set-options-of-commands-called-by-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, the following are several links to SSML parser's composed in different coding languages

- [mimic](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mimic) - [cst_ssml.c](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mimic/blob/391e82fb7b85266b8b1d3de12bbb33265bf92fe5/src/synth/cst_ssml.c)
- [picopi](https://github.com/DougGore/picopi) - [svox_ssml_parser.h](https://github.com/DougGore/picopi/blob/5dea4a36f6e66051d0514407f8d35e35c0d60b18/pico/tts/svox_ssml_parser.h)
- [festival-freebsoft-utils](https://devel.freebsoft.org/festival-freebsoft-utils) - [ssml-mode.scm](http://git.freebsoft.org/?p=festival-freebsoft-utils.git;a=blob;f=ssml-mode.scm;hb=d819e7f5272946285cdb64aa56b41f904ff25f0c)
- [jvoicexml](http://jvoicexml.sourceforge.net/) - [Class SsmlDocument](http://jvoicexml.sourceforge.net/api-0.7.1/org.jvoicexml.xml/org/jvoicexml/xml/ssml/SsmlDocument.html)

The solution is to do the knowledge for self. Use the language that you are currently most familiar with to parse the SSML according to the specification, one element at a time.